# Как отключить пропуск строк в нумерации в Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains

Как отключить пропуск строк в нумерации в Intellij Idea[image: скрин]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ на английском Stackoverflow: [Вот ссылка на ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71877125/6791258)

Перевод:

Это [известный баг](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291945)

Поскольку проблема обычно вызвана длительным обновлением из VCS, это должно помочь, если вы отключите эту опцию:

Settings (Preferences на macOS) | Editor | Inlay Hints | Code Vision | Code authors.

[image: Настройки]

Другие возможные обходные пути:

- Отключите интеграцию с Subversion.
- Добавьте `editor.codeVision.new=false` в Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE.

Как я понял, у вас возможно старая версия Intellij, если это так, то вам следует обновиться.